# Как указать путь, не зная точно местоположения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл по пути: `"C:\Users\blablauser\dist.exe"`
Но если я хочу найти этот файл на другом ПК, где имя пользователя другое, то как мне это сделать?

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Текущая учётная запись может не иметь права доступа к местоположению файла в каталоге чужого профиля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [Path.home](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home)

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.home() / 'dist.exe')

# Если путь нужен в строке
file_name = str(Path.home() / 'dist.exe')
```

Comment: А как сделать, если путь дальше чем user, например - C:\Users\user\folder\file.exe

Comment: @userpy, отделяйте слешами пути: `Path.home() / 'folder' / 'dist.exe'`. Этот оператор был переопределен для упрощения указания пути без заморачивания системными слешами (у винды принятно указывать \, а в юник-подобных /)